# Javascript + Discord.js: RPG levelling system message acting wierd

Tags: javascript, discord.js, referenceerror

I'm making a RPG bot for Discord, and a main part of it is the leveling system. All mathematical systems work, but the message for it (wierdly enough) doesn't. Code:

```
levelUpFunc = function() {
    if (level.exp >= level.lvlupreq) {
        level.lvl += 1;
        level.lvlupreq += level.lvl;
        level.lvlupreq *= 2.5;
        level.exp = 0;
        message.channel.send(`You levelled up to **level ${level.lvl}**! +5 Hp, +1 Atk, +1 Def`);
    }
};
let checkForLvlup = setInterval(() => levelUpFunc(), 500);
```

And the console returns:

```
ReferenceError: message is not defined
```

This is not the case with all other `message.channel.send();`.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't define `message` in the snippet you posted. We would need to see more code to tell you where message is defined. But likely you could add `message` as a parameter of levelUpFunc, and then call it with `levelUpFunc(message)`, assuming that `message` is defined wherever you call this function from.

Comment: As the question title states, I'm using the Javascript library discord.js. It is a predefined function that sends a message. `message.channel.send` sends a message to the channel where the command is called.

Comment: I'm familiar with the library. `message` is a variable, defined normally in a `.on(message => { /*code with message*/ })` block. It's not a magic, global variable that refers to the last message. You need to pass `message` to your function if you want your function to do something in regards to `message`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand, can you clarify please?

Comment: It's difficult for me to know what's confusing you. You need to change your function to take a parameter, `levelUpFunc = function(message) {`, and then when you call the function, you need to call it with the message, `levelUpFunc(message)`. I have now given you the code you need. If this works, please accept my answer, and if you have more questions, please ask them in the Discord.js discord server.